# Set a variable name to a Workbook selected from a VBA ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I will always have Workbook *SQ_Macro_v1* as my main DB.

Two named Workbooks *old_wk* and *new_wk* will have different names, as I will choose them among the currently active WB on my computer.

I am going for a VBA ComboBox listing it all to a choice of mine, but in the end I am not able to store the name of my chosen WB.

```vb
Sub Macro1()

    Dim main_wk, old_wk, new_wk As Workbook

    Set main_wk = Workbooks("SQ_Macro_v1.xlsm")
    Set old_wk = Workbooks(old_chosen) 'also tried UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value
    Set new_wk = Workbooks(FileName_New) '
    
    main_wk.Sheets("Main_DB").Range("C4").Value = old_wk.Worksheets("Sheet 1 Synthese").Range("C35").Value
```

As I run the UserForm code below, the *old_chosen* variable I set as empty in the main Sub. It seems that as I close the UserForm after it runs, nothing remains stored. Any clues to keep that variable saved after I close the UserForm?

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim vWorkbook As Workbook
    ComboBox1.Clear
    For Each vWorkbook In Workbooks
        ComboBox1.AddItem vWorkbook.Name
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If ComboBox1.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        Call YourMacro(ComboBox1)
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub YourMacro(vWorkbookName As String)

    Dim old_chosen As String
    old_chosen = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    MsgBox "You choose: " & Workbooks(vWorkbookName).Name
        
End Sub
```

The MsgBox pops up but no value is stored afterward:

[image: Print stating the empty variable]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Public Sub YourMacro(vWorkbookName As String)
>     Dim old_chosen As String
>     old_chosen = Me.ComboBox1.Value
>     MsgBox "You choose: " & Workbooks(vWorkbookName).Name
> End Sub
> ```

You have declared the variable at [procedure level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#procedure-level) and hence it is not visible after the userform is closed.

To make this variable available to all procedures in the project, precede it with the `Public` statement. Insert a module and paste this there

```
Public old_chosen As String
```

Having said that, I would recommend moving `Macro1` inside the userform and handle the code from there after declaring the variable at [module level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#module-level)